# Can standard field "Name" for sObject be longer than 80 Characters?

Tags: sobject, fields, standard-objects

Question is the title of this question...or do I have to use a custom field?

[image]

Comment: There is an open idea on IdeaExchange to lengthen the Namef field. Looks like it could use some love if you feel so moved: http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XrNfAAK

Answer (score 5):

It can't, 80 is max. Beats me why, my suspicion is it has something to do with UTF-8 encoding of characters (3 bytes / sign * 80 = 240 < 255 which is still a nice VARCHAR2 in underlying Oracle database).

You're more than welcome to use a custom field but I'm sure you're aware what's displayed in links to the record on all related lists, balloon pop-ups, search results etc ;)

Comment: That's what I thought except for the close to 200 references in my source code ... it'd be a long afternoon just to keep someone happy ... keep those title's short people!